# Nvidia Quadro M2000 4GB - does this grapic card meet system requirements?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, image, graph-editor

Does anyone know whether the Nvidia Quadro M2000 4GB meets Blenders minimum system requirements and is compatible?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Maxwell-based card, and will support Blender just fine, including Cycles' CUDA mode. However, Quadros are very expensive compared to the GeForce series for the same GPU core performance, and the extra features of a Quadro will not be useful for Blender. Unless you need a Quadro for some other software you will be using, or some other reason such as non-Blender-related hardware features, or enterprise purchasing requirements that only have Quadros for workstation hardware, you should get a GeForce series card of similar cost, such as a GTX 1070.

Comment: Thank you for your input on my question. That was a great help. cheers!